# how to use context procesors

Tags: python, django

I want to use context processor in `html` template witch shows some information but dont know why doesn't it work properly ?

### Models

```py
class Info(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=28)
    email_address = models.EmailField()
    locations = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

### Context processor

```py
from Blog.models import Info


def info_returner(request):
    return {'number':Info.phone_number,
           'address': Info.locations}
```

### Template HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h5>{{ number }}</h5>
      <span>PHONE NUMBER</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h5>{{ email }}</h5>
      <span>EMAIL ADDRESS</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h5>{{ location }}</h5>
      <span>STREET ADDRESS</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As said I was trying to show user some info by context processors but don't know what's wrong with above code .

Comment: Info.phone_number` is a column, not the phone number of a *record*, you did not specify what record to use...

Comment: How can I do that ?